# How recursion will work?

Tags: java

Can anyone Explain how this recursion program going to work.I tried and run this program I got Output : But I am not Understanding flow of the program.

**MyCode**:

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("i am caller" + new NewClass().mystery("DELIVER"));
    }
    public String mystery(String s) {
        System.out.println("sssss" + s);
        String s1 = s.substring(0, 1);      
        String s2 = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1);   
        String s3 = s.substring(s.length() - 1);      
        if (s.length() <= 3) {          
            return s3 + s2 + s1;
        } else {           
            return s1 + mystery(s2) + s3;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: get a pen and paper, write the return value on each iteration

Comment: A debugger is your friend.

Comment: That System.out is basically a digital version of your suggestion though. Having the actual values does not seem to help.

Comment: ya i wrote and print sops also output is: DEVILER according to me output:VIL

Comment: Start with a simpler example. Paste this into your browser's console: `function f(x) { console.log(x); if (x > 0) f(x - 1); }` then call it with `f(8)`

Comment: @ Daniel Earwicker I am using netbeans Ide how to debug above code

Comment: you want learn Recursion go this site                                                                               "http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/23recursion/" now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the single steps:

```
mystery("DELIVER")
print "sssssDELIVER"
s1 = D
s2 = ELIVE
S3 = R
DELIVER.length <= 3 ?  -> no

     mystery("ELIVE")
     print "sssssELIVE"
     s1 = E
     s2 = LIV
     s3 = E
     ELIVE.length <= 3 ? -> no

         mystery("LIV")
         print "sssssLIV"
         s1 = L
         s2 = I
         s3 = V
         LIV.length <= 3 ? -> yes
         return VIL

     return E + VIL + E

return D + EVILE + R
print "i am callerDEVILER"
```

Hope you understand it now!

Comment: but only one return is possible to the caller method

Comment: one return is possible to one instance of the caller method and in this example the method "mystery" (i think this is the method you call caller method) is called 3 times till the given string is smaller or equals than 3 and then there is one return for every instance of the method.

Comment: from main method we are calling only once so ?

Comment: yes from main we are calling it only once, but the method call itself but all the time with a smaller given string and this happens till the string is smaller or equals 3. that is called recursion. if the method cannot call itself, than it is no recursiv method.

Comment: 1st time s2 is:ELIVE it will not go into if loop its ok and 2nd time s2 is: LIV it will go into if block it has to print VIL but its printing ELIVE how it is can u explain me.

Comment: first call: s2 is ELIVE then the next call happens with s2=ELIVE as given parameter. then while 2nd call s2 is created als LIV but it didnt go into the if block because it checks if the given string(ELIVE) is <= 3 and not the substring s2. Then the method is called once again with s2=LIV as parameter. now while the 3rd call it will go into the if block because LIV <= 3 and the it will return VIL the secound call will return  E+VIL+E then third call will return D+EVILE+R and then the sentence i am callerDEVILER is printed.

Comment: the other three outputs before happened after the call of the functions and they are always print exactly sssss+the string which is passed to the function.

Comment: pls take a better look at my answer...it descibes exactly what happened in the single steps.

Answer (score 0):

s1 will take the `first char`, `s3` will take `the last char` and `s2` will take everything between the first char and the last char. then you are checking if the string `length is less or equal 3` or not, 
if yes it will `return s1,s2,s3` as one string else 
it will `return`D + mystery(s2)="ELIVE" + R . then `D +E + mystery(s2)="LIV" +E +R` and since it is three chars it will return `D +E + L + I + V +E + R`

Comment: for First time s1 is D and 2nd time s1 is E and 2rd time s1 is L and third time it will go into if loop then it has to print LIV